# If value is empty don't add class attr upon append

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsbin.com/guvixara/1/edit

I'm dynamically adding a button...

```
$(".confirm-add-button").on("click", function() {
  var $ctrl = $('<button/>').attr({ class: $('.newbtnclassname').val()}).html($('.newbtntxt').val());
  $(".drawing-area").append($ctrl);
  UpdateView();
});
```

However I don't (as in do **NOT**) want to add the class attribute if the `$('.newbtnclassname').val()` is blank.

If anyone can help with this it'll be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd do that like this

```
$(".confirm-add-button").on("click", function() {
    var klass = $('.newbtnclassname').val(),
        text  = $('.newbtntxt').val(),
        obj   = {};

    if (klass) obj['class'] = klass;
    if (text)  obj['text']  = text;

    $(".drawing-area").append( $('<button />', obj) );
    UpdateView();
});
```

[**JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/guvixara/2/edit)

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a huge help!

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
  $(".confirm-add-button").on("click", function() {
    var $ctrl = $('<button/>').attr({ class: $('.newbtnclassname').val()}).html($('.newbtntxt').val());
    if($('.newbtnclassname').val() != ""){//add this if statement
      $(".drawing-area").append($ctrl);
    }
    UpdateView();
  });
```

here is the [link](http://jsbin.com/guvixara/3/edit)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a simple if condition:

```
$(".confirm-add-button").on("click", function() {
    var $ctrl = $('<button/>').html($('.newbtntxt').val());
    var cssClass = $('.newbtnclassname').val();
    if (cssClass != "") {
        $ctrl.addClass(cssClass);
    }
    $(".drawing-area").append($ctrl);
    UpdateView();
});
```